# Only run animation on page load, NOT run when container shows up again

Tags: css, animation

```
<div>
  <p class="bounceIn">
    Hello world
  </p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2fr1tcv6/

After page load, these elements are visible, so the bounceIn animation runs.

But on the page users can click a button and hide the div, and re-show it. When the div shows again, I don't want the animation to run. Is there a way to achieve with CSS properties?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the bounceIn class from the P tag. Something like this:

```
  $("button").click(
  function(){
    $("div").toggle();
    $("p").removeClass("bounceIn");
  });
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without removing the CSS class?